# RSpec: Matching arguments for receive_message_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to stub:

```
Thing.where(uuid: options['uuid']).first
```

Via:

```
allow(Thing).to receive_message_chain(:where, :first)
  .with(uuid: thing_double.uuid)
  .and_return(nil)
```

But this is returning:

```
 #<Double (anonymous)> received :first with unexpected arguments
         expected: ({:uuid=>123})
              got: (no args)
```

Is there a different way I should be validating arguments for message chains?

Comment: Wouldn't it be written `allow(Thing).to receive_message_chain(:where).first`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you can use `with` in combination with `receive_message_chain` when the arguments pertain anything other than the final method. Thus the message:

```
#<Double (anonymous)> received :first with unexpected arguments
```

This makes sense -- how can RSpec know which method in the chain should receive the arguments?

To verify the argument expectation, don't stub the chain, just stub `where`

```
allow(Thing).to receive(:where).with(uuid: 1).and_return([])
expect(Thing.where(uuid: 1).first).to eq nil
```

Or omit the arguments:

```
 allow(Thing).to receive_message_chain(:where, :first).and_return(nil)
 expect(Thing.where(uuid: 1).first).to eq nil
```

`receive_message_chain` is not recommended IMO. From the docs:

> you should consider any use of receive_message_chain a code smell

Answer (score 9):

Here's how we addresses a similar situation:

```
expect(Theme).to receive(:scoped).and_return(double('scope').tap do |scope| 
  expect(scope).to receive(:includes).with(:categories).and_return scope
  expect(scope).to receive(:where).with(categories: { parent_id: '1'}).and_return scope
  expect(scope).to receive(:order).with('themes.updated_at DESC').and_return scope
  expect(scope).to receive(:offset).with(10).and_return scope
  expect(scope).to receive(:limit).with(10000)
end)
```

In recent months, by pure accident, I discovered that you can actually chain your "with" invocation in the order of the message chain. Thus, the previous example, becomes this:

```
expect(Theme).to receive_message_chain(:scoped, :includes, :where, :order, :offset, :limit).with(no_args).with(:categories).with(categories: { parent_id: '1'}).with('themes.updated_at DESC').with(10).with(10000)
```

Comment: Even better you can `let(:verifying_double) { instance_double(YourClass) }` and then `….and_return(verifying_double)` and then `expect(verifying_double).to…` – this way it's clearer without nesting.

Answer (score 4):

It's sometimes error prone (I'll intermittently get an error saying "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1+)"; although this seems to only happen when performing multiple receive_message_chains in a single test), but you can also opt for chaining your "with" methods thus:

```
expect(User).to receive_message_chain(:where, :order).with(active: true).with('name ASC')
```

Comment: Nope. This will execute and pass, but it does not actually test the `with` parameter. (as of rspec 3.10, at least) Change `:where, :order` or `name ASC` to *anything* else, and you'll see your test still (misleadingly) pass.

Comment: @DavidHempy you are incorrect.

The following passes:
 `expect(NameserverPair).to receive_message_chain(:order, :first).with('domains_count ASC').with(no_args)`

The following does *not*:
`expect(NameserverPair).to receive_message_chain(:order, :first).with('domains_count ASC').with('bork')`

It correctly fails with:
`Failure/Error: order('domains_count ASC').first

       #<Double (anonymous)> received :first with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("bork")
              got: (no args)`

This is precisely the correct behaviour, using RSpec 3.7